# need to understand the io_service boost object

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

given this sample

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using boost::asio::ip::udp;

std::string make_daytime_string()
{
  using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
  time_t now = time(0);
  return ctime(&now);
}

class udp_server
{
public:
  udp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port)
     : socket_(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port))
  {
    start_receive();
  }

private:
  void start_receive()
  {
    socket_.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), remote_endpoint_,
        boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_receive, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
  {
    if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::message_size)
    {
      boost::shared_ptr<std::string> message(
          new std::string(make_daytime_string()));

      socket_.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(*message), remote_endpoint_,
          boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_send, this, message,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

      start_receive();
    }
  }

  void handle_send(boost::shared_ptr<std::string> /*message*/,
      const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
      std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
  {
  }

  udp::socket socket_;
  udp::endpoint remote_endpoint_;
  boost::array<char, 1> recv_buffer_;
};

int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<udp_server>> servers;
    for (unsigned short port = 5000; port != 6000; ++port)
    {
        servers.push_back(std::shared_ptr<udp_server>(new 
                          udp_server(io_service, port)));
    }
    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I have 1000 udp_client s that send 1000 request using a given port : ./udp_client port &

e.g.

./udp_client 5000 &
./udp_client 5001 &
...
./udp_client 6000

I want to process all the requests at the same time
Do I need to run each server in a separate thread?
If it's true, a single instance of io_service is sufficient or I need to create an instance per thread.

Thanks.

Comment: There are *many* approaches. 1) process each request serially. 2) process each request in a separate process. 3) process each request in a separate thread. 4) use a pool of threads or processes to handle multiple requests each. 5) use a state machine to process multiple requests in a single thread in small chunks. 6) many more..

Comment: I want to use a thread per connection. In this case, a single instance of io_service is sufficient or I need to create an instance per thread?

Comment: A single instance of io_service is sufficient. I recommend a thread pool for what you want, since you probably don't actually want to spawn 1000 threads, rather some independent number you can control. Just call io_service::run() from all the worker threads and they'll get a share of the events.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Is there a sample for this proposition in the boost documentation?